# Conversion failed in procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the error while executing  below code 
   The dates are coming like below

```
   Where (EndDate >= '13 Nov 2017 0:0:00PM' and  
   EndDate < Convert(DateTime, '13 Nov 2017 0:0:00PM')+1)
```

The above is coming as a param value in the procedure
   Basically need to convert '13 Nov 2017 0:0:00PM' to datetime
   in the query.This is a `enter code here`filter condition in SP

```
@Filter=N'(EndDate >= ''13 Nov 2017 0:0:00PM'' and  EndDate < 
   Convert(DateTime, ''13 Nov 2017 0:0:00PM'')+1)
```

Is the dates coming wrong in SP or can I change it to datetime inside 
   SP body.

Comment: hint: use of `cast (your date as datetime)`

Comment: Use a date(time) for the parameter instead of a string and the problem goes away

Comment: use parameters instead of concatenating date values into a query. It will solve your problem, and will run faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Answer:

```
@Filter=N'(EndDate >= CAST(LEFT(''13 Nov 2017 00:00:00PM'',11) AS DATETIME) and  EndDate < 
   CAST(LEFT(''13 Nov 2017 00:00:00PM'',11) AS DATETIME)+1)'
```